# Ansible: extract values from nested dictionary object (JSON)

Tags: json, filter, ansible

I am transforming existing installation shell scripts for one application to Ansible job. I am now stock on step where i have to find given set of files and later use them in other task with another properties in nested loop. Problem is I can't find the way how to transform find result to usable form.

Steps:

```
- name: Finds files to use
  find:
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    file_type: file
    use_regex: yes
    recurse: yes
    patterns:
      - ".*\\.xml$"
      - ".*\\.yml$"
      - ".*\\.hcl$"
      - ".*\\.json$"
  with_items:
    - /etc/<<some_folder>>
    - /opt/<<some_folder>>/conf
    - /opt/<<some_folder>>/x-cluster
    - /opt/<<some_folder>>/config
    - /opt/<<some_folder>>/x_worker/config
  register: "findoutput"

- name: Replace var strings
  replace:
    path: "{{ item.0.path }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.1   }}"
    replace: "{{ item.2 }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ findoutput | **<<insert_magic>>** | list }}"
    - "{{ replace_values | dictsort }}"
```

This approach keeps failing because I am recieving list of 5 values, each from one search iteration, which has nested all the found files and I haven't found way to access this for my use.

I will be glad for any help or point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the find task, flatten `find` output and fetch only the `path` value like below:

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    formatted_result: "{{ findoutput.results | json_query('[*].files[*].path') | list | flatten }}"
```

Then use `formatted_result` list on your next task to replace strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked :) What i was missing was the knowledge of json_query modifiers.